# What is the gradient of $f=\| S-ABA^T \|^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, matrix-calculus

What is $\nabla f$ respect to $B$ and $A$ if

$$f=\|S-ABA^T \|^2$$

where $S\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times k}$ and $B\in \mathbb R^{k\times k}$?  What is $\nabla f$ respect to only $B$?

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: I use Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For convenience, let $M = (ABA^T - S)$.

Now express the function and its differential in terms of the [Frobenius (:) product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product)
$$\eqalign{
     f &= M:M \cr\cr
    df &= 2\,M:dM \cr
       &= 2\,M:(A\,dB\,A^T) + 2\,M:(dA\,BA^T) + 2\,M:(AB\,dA^T) \cr
       &= 2\,A^TMA:dB   + 2\,(MAB^T+M^TAB):dA \cr
}$$
Setting $dA=0$ yields the gradient with respect to $B$ 
$$\eqalign{
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial B} = 2\,A^TMA \cr
}$$
And setting $dB=0$ yields
$$\eqalign{
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial A} = 2\,MAB^T + 2\,M^TAB \cr
}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Euclidean norm for the matrices you have $$n(A)=\Vert A \Vert^2= \text{tr}(A.A^T)$$ whose derivative is $$n(A).h=2 \text{tr}(A^T.h)$$

Now, let's consider $$l(A,B)=S-A.B.A^T.$$ You have $$\nabla_A l(A.B).h =-h.B.A^T-A.B.h^T$$ and $$\nabla_B l(A.B).h =-A.h.A^T$$ You can now apply the chain rule as $$f(A,B)=(n \circ l)(A,B)$$ to get

$$\nabla_A f(A.B).h =-2\text{tr}((S-A.B.A^T)(h.B.A^T+A.B.h^T))$$ and

$$\nabla_B f(A.B).h =-2\text{tr}((S-A.B.A^T)(A.h.A^T))$$

Comment: what do you denote by $h$?

Comment: $\nabla_A f$ and $\nabla_B f$ are functions of matrices. $h$ is the matrice variable I use to explain the values of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

First let us recall that the trace of a matrix $X=(X_{ij})_{n\times n}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is 
$
\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(X)=\sum_{u=1}^nX_{uu}.
$
And the Frobenius norm of a matrix $X=(x_{ij})_{n\times n}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is  given in terms of the trace 
$$
\| X\|^2=\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(X^TX)
=\mathop{\mbox{trace }}\Big(\big(\sum_{u=1}^{n}X_{iu}\cdot X_{uj}\big)_{n\times n}\Big)
=\sum_{v=1}^{n}\big(\sum_{u=1}^{n}X_{vu}\cdot X_{uv}\big).
$$
And the Frobenius inner prodoct  in matrix linear space $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is 
$$
\langle X,Y\rangle = \mathop{\mbox{trace}}(X^TY)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nX_{ij}Y_{ji}
$$
In the case of your question we have
$$
\| S - ABA^{T}\|^2
=
\mathop{\mbox{trace }}((S - ABA^T)^{T}(S - ABA^{T}))
$$
Note that 
\begin{align}
(S - ABA^T)^{T}(S - ABA^{T})
=
&
(S^T - (ABA^T)^T)(S - ABA^T)
\\
=&
(S^{T} - ABA^{T})(S - ABA^{T})
\\
=&
S^TS-SABA^{T}-ABA^{T}S+ABA^{T}ABA^{T}
\end{align}
Then 
$$
f(A,B)=\| S-ABA^T\|^2= \mathop{\mbox{trace }}(S^TS)
-\mathop{\mbox{trace}}(SABA^T)
-\mathop{\mbox{trace}}(ABA^TS)
+\mathop{\mbox{trace}}(ABA^TABA^T)
$$
Fix $A$ and $B$. 
By definition, the gradient $\nabla_Bf(A,B)$ of aplication $f$ in $(A,B)$ with respect $B$ is the matrix of the  linear application derivative
$$
\begin{array}{rrcl}
D_Bf(A,B) &: \mathbb{R}^{k\times n}&\longrightarrow &\mathbb{R}
\\
\quad & V&\longmapsto & \langle\nabla_Bf(A,B), V\rangle
\end{array}
$$
that satisfies the condition
$$
f(A+V,B)-f(A,B)=\langle \nabla_B f(A_0,B_0), V\rangle+ \|V\|\cdot r(V) 
$$
for some function $r:\mathbb{R}^{k\times n}\to \mathbb{R}$such that $\lim_{V\to 0}r(V)=0$.

\begin{align}
f(A,B+V)-f(A,B)
=& 
-\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(SA(B+V)A^T)+\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(SABA^T)
\\
&
-\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(A(B+V)A^TS)+\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(ABA^TS)
\\
&
+\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(A(B+V)A^TA(B+V)BA^T)-\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(ABA^TABA^T)
\\
=& 
-\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(SAVA^T)
\\
&
-\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(AVA^TS)
\\
&
+\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(AVA^TABA^T)
+\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(ABA^TAVA^T)
+\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(AVA^TAVA^T)
\\
\end{align}
Now we join the portions which are linear function of $V$: 
\begin{align}
-\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(SAVA^T)=& -\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(A^TSAV)  ,
\\
-\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(AVA^TS)=& -\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(A^TSAV) ,
\\
\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(AVA^TABA^T)=&\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(A^TABA^TAV),
\\
\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(ABA^TAVA^T)=&\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(A^TABA^TAV) ,
\end{align} Equalities above, following the fact that the trace is invariant under cyclic permutations. 
Then we use the trace linearity for equality 
$\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(AVA^TAVA^T)=
\frac{1}{\|V\|}\cdot\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(A\frac{1}{\|V\|}VA^TAVA^T)$.
Thus, we get
\begin{align}
f(A,B+V)-f(A,B)
= 
&
\underbrace{\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(2(-A^TSA+A^TABA^TA)V)}_{\langle\nabla_{B}f(A,B), V\rangle}
\\
&
+\|V\|\cdot\underbrace{\mathop{\mbox{trace }}(A\frac{1}{\|V\|}VA^TAVA^T)}_{r(V)}
\end{align}
Then
$$
\nabla_{B}f(A,B)=2(-A^TSA+A^TABA^TA)=-2A^T(S-ABA^T)A
$$

The calculation of the gradient $\nabla_{(A,B)}f(A_0,B_0)$ with respect to variable  $(A,B)$ and the rest $r(H,V)$ of the  difference $f(A_0+H,B_0+V)-f(A_0,B_0)$ is a little more laborious. But the method is analogous.

Comment: Great Answer! Thank you :)